# Can one CUIT test support testing two applications that are on different computers?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, coded-ui-tests

Can one Coded UI test support the testing of two applications that are on different computers and where the steps rely on each app's test results?

Two applications are resident on two computers. E.g. **App1** on **Comp1**, and **App2** on **Comp2**. The two computers are connected via Ethernet. **App1** and **App2** talk to each other via TCP/IP. Is it possible within one Coded UI test case to control both **App1** and **App2** simultaneously, where the actions on **App1** need to rely on the results of executing **App2**. E.g. click on button **A** on **App1** if label **B** on **App2** == "**Sent**".

Notice, **App1** and **App2** are on different computers.

Answer (score 1):

You can't run one test on two different computers at the same time and you can't access another computer's UI from one computer via CUIT. The best solution would be to write two tests: one for App1 and another for App2, and implement a simple socket communication between the two applications/computers and run them locally with mstest or in VS with test agents on the test computers. App1 does some things (click on button A) then waits for a message on the socket from App2. App2 does some things (triggered by App1) then sends message to App1 (label B == "Sent"). App1 gets the message, continues test accordingly.

Comment: thanks, i was thinking the same way if there is no alternative way. another question arises up. is it possible run different CUIT test cases on separate computers without test controllers and also conduct msg delivery for communication between them.

Comment: You can use MSTest.exe in command line to start your tests (%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\). It installs with the test agent. You just need a batch script on your developer computer that starts the tests on the test machines asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

Coded UI test need access to mouse and keyboard. If you can do the test manual form one computer normally the CUIT can do it the same way.

From my point of view this is really difficult for your mentioned test case. When you run the test on **Comp1** how will you get access to mouse and keyboard form **Comp2**? Maybe a remote-console can help you.

Comment: i haven't tried CUIT any test cases via remote desk. have you tried this way? if it's a possible way, it will be a good news for me for a temporary solution. thanks for your input.

Comment: No, I haven't tried it until now. I wouldn't bet that it will work - only a try.